# mysql not reading special utf8 (øœå) characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

After reading from my database, special characters are not displayed correctly.

I am connecting to my database in this fashion:

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB     connection');

mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

?>
```

I am reading the database in this fashion:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM tags ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    //Read each tag into a span-menu
    echo "<div class=\"span-3\"id=\"".$row['id']."\">"."<a href=\"activities.php?tag_id=".$row['id']."&tag=".$row['name']."\"><h5>".$row['name']."</h5></a></div>\n ";

}
```

The table contains correct characters, so the problem is when they are read....

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: What do you see and what are you supposed to see?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be your HTML page which is showing the wrong encoding, rather than mysql (or your query).

If you are using HTML5, add the following to the `<head>` of your html:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

If you are using HTML4/XHTML, it's:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You can see which encoding your page is returning and test different encodings using your browser. In Chrome, click View > Encoding.

Comment: I added the html5 code above. I am using <!DOCTYPE html> so i assume thats html5 :) But, it didn't do anything to the characters....still the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you check the current encoding in your browser?